# Windows Azure Virtual Machine Reverse DNS PTR Solution?

Tags: azure, dns, virtual-machine

I am looking for a creative solution to Windows Virtual Machine not supporting reverse dns.  I have a Windows Virtual machine in Azure and I am running a low demand email server on it.  Google will not except emails from the my server because reverse dns is supported in Azure VMs yet.  So if a user wants their company email forwarded to a Gmail account, it will fail.  Any ideas ?

Comment: It is also possible that there are problems with receiving emails too, not just sending them. I would not be surprised if some mail servers can refuse to send stuff to you if you don't have a proper PTR record.

Comment: They have accepted the proposal to add the ability to set PTR records, and said it's on their roadmap. For more info, see http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/34192-general-feedback-/suggestions/3090834-provide-reverse-dns-ptr-records-for-virtual-mach

Comment: Isn't this ridiculous? haven't MS really really messed up by not providing this from day one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse DNS is now available for Azure: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/

Comment: I have this working on several Azure sites now.  Very nice feature.

Comment: Note, in the new Azure Portal, you can't currently set up reverse DNS if you selected the Resource Manager deployment model when you created your VM (so use Classic instead).

Comment: Note that this has now been kneecapped by Microsoft adding Azure compute resource IP addresses to black lists: [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2016/04/04/sending-e-mail-from-azure-compute-resource-to-external-domains/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2016/04/04/sending-e-mail-from-azure-compute-resource-to-external-domains/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the SendGrid can help you achieve what you are looking for.  Here are the details about it:
http://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/index.html

here is the documentation for the technicalities:

http://sendgrid.com/docs/

I hope this helps you, let me know if you need anything else.