# Adding Reverse DNS for Azure Email VM

Tags: azure, dns

I am a fresh user in azure, i created a windows VM and installed hMailServer on it, when i send emails to some recipients i get the following error:

Remote server replied: 550 5.7.1 Connections not accepted from servers without a valid sender domain.flph396 Fix reverse DNS for 000.00.000.000

the IP(000.00.000.000) is not my vm IP.

i tried

Set-AzureService –ServiceName “contosoapp1” –Description “App1 with Reverse DNS” –ReverseDnsFqdn “contosoapp1.cloudapp.net.”
but its not working, i used my vm fqdn and my own a record for mail "mail.myDomain.com" but nothing worked.

Comment: are you getting any type of error or response after typing in your command?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Windows Azure Virtual Machine Reverse DNS PTR Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927725/windows-azure-virtual-machine-reverse-dns-ptr-solution/25300410#25300410)

Note that issue that Azure compute IP addresses are added to spam blacklists by Microsoft.